# Laravel: Missing required parameter

Tags: php, database, laravel

this is the form

```
<form action="{{ route('addtocart', $product->id) }}" method="get">
 @csrf
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg py-2 mt-5" type="submit" style="border-radius: 10px; height:50px; width:200px;"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

this is the web route

```
Route::get('/product-details/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'products'])->name('product.details');
Route::get('/product-lists', function () {
     return view('products.product-list');
});
Route::get('/add-to-cart', [ProductController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('addtocart');
```

my ProductController

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if($request->session()->get('name'))
        {
            $cart = new Cart;
            $cart -> user_id = $request -> session() -> get('name')['id'];
            $cart -> product_id = $request -> product_id;
            $cart -> save();
            return redirect()->route('product.details')->with('added', 'Added to cart');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

when im adding product to cart, It shows this error

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: product.details] [URI: product-details/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].

Comment: return redirect()->route('product.details',['id' => $id])->with('added', 'Added to cart'); pass id in route

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your route expects an id to be passed, on your action in the form use

```
<form action="{{route('addtocart', ['id'=>$product->id])}" method="get">
   @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg py-2 mt-5" type="submit" 
        style="border-radius: 10px; height:50px; width:200px;"><i 
      class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add to cart</button>
 </form>
```